# OpenFin Chrome version must be >= 66.0.3359.181

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, version, chromium, openfin

So I was using ChromeDriver 2.40 which worked great with OpenFin 10.66.41.18 or Chromium 66.0.3359.181 if you prefer.

However after upgrading to latest OpenFin stable version (11.69.42.29), I started getting an error denoting version mismatch between ChromeDriver and Chromium:
Chrome version must be >= 66.0.3359.181

Fair enough, I thought and downloaded Chromedriver 2.44 which is the closest I can get to v69, still getting an error:
Chrome version must be >= 69.0.3497.0

So, close but no cigar as OpenFin now runs on Chromium 69.0.3497.128

But that means we reached a dead end completely losing the ability to automate OpenFin as if you get the next available ChromeDriver (so 2.45) you get an error that chrome:
Chrome version must be between 70 and 73

In other words, latest stable version of OpenFin is not supported with a matching ChromeDriver. Just raising this in case anyone else is experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I reverted back to 10.66.41.18 as I'm using a config file to launch my app.
So, I've changed from:

```
    "runtime": {
    "version": "stable"
     }
```

to this one:

```
  "runtime": {
    "version": "10.66.41.18"
  }
```